# ffserver-2.2 - streaming an ASF video as OGG output with ffserver on Debian 7.5

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, debian-wheezy

I'm trying to stream an IP webcam ASF live stream to a ffserver to output an OGG format. The server starts successfully but the ffserver commands used to feed the ffserver fails with a segment fault.

### Input stream

```
$ ffprobe http://account:password@webcam/videostream.asf

Input #0, asf, from 'http://account:password@webcam/videostream.asf':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc), 640x480, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: adpcm_ima_wav ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16p, 32 kb/s
```

### ffserver configuration

my ffserver configuration is :

```
Port 8091
RTSPPort 554
BindAddress 192.168.1.62
MaxHTTPConnections 1000
MaxClients 100
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -

<Feed webcam.ffm>
        File /tmp/webcam.ffm
        FileMaxSize 500M
        ACL allow localhost
        ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255

</Feed>

<Stream webcam.ogg>
        Feed                    webcam.ffm
        InputFormat             asf

        Format                  ogg
        Preroll                 15

        VideoCodec              libtheora
        VideoFrameRate          7
        VideoSize               640x480
        PixelFormat             yuv420p
        Qscale                  7
        VideoBitRate            256
        VideoBufferSize         40

        AudioCodec              libvorbis
        AudioBitRate            64
        StartSendOnKey
</Stream>


<Stream status.html>
        Format status
        # Only allow local people to get the status
        ACL allow localhost
        ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Stream>
```

### ffmpeg feed

I run the following command that fails

```
$ ffmpeg  -i http://account:password@webcam/videostream.asf http://ffserver_ip:port/webcam.ffm
Input #0, asf, from 'http://account:password@webcam/videostream.asf':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc), 640x480, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: adpcm_ima_wav ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 8000 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
[swscaler @ 0x36a80c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Segmentation fault
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please include complete console outputs. Your outputs are missing the version and configuration information which can be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FFSERVER - streaming an ASF video as Webm output](http://superuser.com/questions/762132/ffserver-streaming-an-asf-video-as-webm-output)

Answer (score 0):

this work for me without audio

`<Feed cam1.ffm>
  File /tmp/cam1.ffm
  FileMaxSize 10000K
  ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>`

`<Stream vid.ogg>
   Feed cam1.ffm
   Format ogg
   VideoCodec libtheora
   VideoFrameRate 15
   VideoSize vga
   VideoBitRate 320
   VideoBufferSize 40
   VideoGopSize 12
   VideoQMin 1
   VideoQMax 31
   Preroll 0
   AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
   NoAudio StartSendOnKey
</Stream>`

to reload my server

```
ffserver -f /etc/ffserver.conf reload
```

to start my feed

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8888/cam1.ffm
```

to play video streaming from html

```
<video controls>
    <source src="http://192.168.1.104:8888/vid.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.  
</video>
```